# Uploadify IO Error in Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, io, uploadify

I'm trying to get a basic example set up with Uploadify and my code works in all browsers except for Chrome.

Basically, all I'm trying to do is let a user pick an image to be embedded in the page. The user chooses a file, and on selecting one, the file is sent, via Uploadify, to my C# handler which converts the image to a base-64 encoded string, and sends it back to be placed into the `src` of the target `img`.

**Here's my JS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Uploadify/uploadify.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Content/Uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {
      $("#fileUpload").uploadify({
         'swf': 'Content/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
         'uploader': 'ImageHandler.ashx',
         'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
            $("#theImage").attr("src", data);
          },
          'onUploadError': function (file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
             alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
          }
       });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<img id="theImage" height="300" width="300"/>
```

**And here's my handler code:**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
   {
      byte[] bytes = null;
      using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(context.Request.Files[0].InputStream))
      {
         bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(context.Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
         var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

         var imgSource = "data: " + context.Request.ContentType + ";base64," + base64;

         context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
         context.Response.Write(imgSource);
      }
   }

   context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
   context.Response.Write("");

}
```

As you can see, it is very simple and works in FF, IE (even the IE 5 emulator w/ IE 11!), Safari, but when in Chrome (**v. 31.0.1650.63 m**) the `onUploadError` function gets hit and the error variables are as follows:

> 1. file: [file Object]
> 2. errorCode: -220
> 3. errorMsg: Error #2038
> 4. errorString: IO Error

I'm using the latest version of Uploadify (just downloaded from Uploadify.com last night, **v. 3.2.1**).

Has anyone seen this before or know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

After doing some Google searches, it appears that some users have gone the route of disabling Flash in Chrome and I can verify this works but I do not like this as a solution. If you go to the Chrome Plugins page there are 2 versions installed:

[image: Chrome plugins page]

If I disable the first one in the list, my Uploadify works fine but I wouldn't expect my users to have to do this.

**SOLUTION:**

Since the entire point of me using Uploadify was to send the image to a handler, and use the response of the handler without a page refresh, and that handler is only converting the image to a base64 encoded string, I would use HTML 5's `FileReader` where available. So for Chrome, FF, IE 10 & up, Uploadify won't even be used. Here is my new code that works across browsers:

```
$(function () {
   if (Modernizr.filereader) {
      var $fileUpload = $("#fileUpload");
      $fileUpload.on("change", function (e) {
         var files = e.target.files;
         if (files.length) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
               $("#theImage").attr("src", reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
         }
      });
   } else {
      // browser doesn't support the HTML 5 file reader api, so fall back to Uploadify:
      $("#fileUpload").uploadify({
         'swf': 'Content/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
         'uploader': 'ImageHandler.ashx',
         'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
            $("#theImage").attr("src", data);
         },
         'onUploadError': function (file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: are you using this agains localhost? Chrome has restrictions to localhost in terms of some operations, maybe uploading is one of these? If this is so, the problem will likely disappear once you run this on a hosted deployment.

Comment: I am using localhost right now. Let me put it on an IIS site quick and try it. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work - same error. Unless Chrome has restrictions on local sites as well as localhost? (I'm now hitting my site via machine name instead of localhost)

Comment: I'm afraid I have mislead you. According to this post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swfupload/Xb5v7jcuamU/ITPURIqzZWgJ, it seems Uploadify uses a flash component that does not work in Chrome

Comment: See my update. It should work in Chrome.. it appears to have something to do with the Flash versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for now will be to use Modernizr to detect if the HTML 5 File API is available (specifically the `FileReader`). If available, I'll use the `FileReader` to convert the image to a base 64 encoded string and use that in the `img`'s `src` attribute.

```
$(function () {
   if (Modernizr.filereader) {
      var $fileUpload = $("#fileUpload");
      $fileUpload.on("change", function (e) {
         var files = e.target.files;
         if (files.length) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
               $("#theImage").attr("src", reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
         }
      });
   } else {
      // browser doesn't support the HTML 5 file reader api, so fall back to Uploadify:
      $("#fileUpload").uploadify({
         'swf': 'Content/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
         'uploader': 'ImageHandler.ashx',
         'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
            $("#theImage").attr("src", data);
         },
         'onUploadError': function (file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to write the solution (the part after __SOLUTION:__ ...) in the answer, as it will look more consistent with the Q&A format in Stack Overflow. Glad you solved the issue BTW.

Comment: Good call, I normally do but was in somewhat of a hurry yesterday. Thanks again for the help.